# How to display article when tag id is given in joomla module

Tags: php, joomla

I want to display articles content when tag id is given.
When i create an article i want to display that article in two modules but as two different types.
for an example.if i create article i want to display it in two categories. like multiple categories.

so i want to add two tags and display it in two modules.

is there any way to display article contents by using joomla `contentitem_tag_map` table.

for an example display the article in `contentitem_tag_map` table `where tag_id=1` likewise.

anyone know any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could create a module to do that but I'd first off suggest looking at the ones on the J[oomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display)(JED), I'd start with extensions in the [Articles Display category](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display).

Five seconds of searching and I found this module [FJ Related Articles Plus](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/related-items/6195) that uses tags to display related articles.

If nothing else, as JED extensions are all open source, you can download one that's close to what you need and modify it to your exact requirements.